# oracle, extract multiple substring from a string

Tags: sql, regex, string, oracle, substring

Trying to extract two numeric values (8 and 10) from below string as two new columns.

Tried to benefit from the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43105555/oracle-extract-multiple-substrings-from-a-string) question but couldn't solve this one.

Any help appreciated!

```
'{"someInconsiderableText1": {"answer": "8", "question": "someInconsiderableText2"}, "someInconsiderableText3": {"answer": "10", "question": "someInconsiderableText4"}}'
```

Comment: Your question is a bit vague about what you want to do. Do you only want the numbers 8 and 10 or are you looking for any JSON value to an answer object? And what version of Oracle (newer versions have JSON parsing libraries)?

Comment: @ Sam M, the string I've provided above is the value of a CLOB field in the Oracle data warehouse (Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production). This field includes the answers of two separate questions. What I need is to select/extract the answers to these questions as two different fields. Hope it is clearer now. In brief, I need two new fields, the first one will have the value '8' and the second one '10'.

Comment: Native JSON support was introduced in Oracle 12c. I've read about this third-party JSON parsing library for Oracle but never used it --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30393214/support-for-json-in-oracle-11g. It's tempting to try JSON string manipulation with regex but gets complicated quickly and is error prone. You're better of trying to use a JSON library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this help?

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '{"someInconsiderableText1": {"answer": "8", "question": "someInconsiderableText2"},
"someInconsiderableText3": {"answer": "10", "question": "someInconsiderableText4"}}'
  3     from dual
  4    )
  5  select replace(regexp_substr(col, '"\d+"', 1, 1), '"') first,
  6         replace(regexp_substr(col, '"\d+"', 1, 2), '"') second
  7  from test;

FIRST      SECOND
---------- ----------
8          10

SQL>
```